# give full control folder access to one process in Windows

Tags: windows, folder-permissions

I've got an important resource folder (that can not be embeded in exe file) and I want to limit access of all Windows users except Admin Group ones. My program runs in normal (not Admin) user and I want give resource folder access only to this process. I can ask Admin user's password once, but I don't know is it possible or not?

Comment: I used **runas** command for executing my program under admin user permission. Is it a bad solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can start an elevated rights process from you application, do whatever is needed with admin rights and end it after.

Take a look here: http://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-1/

Comment: does xp support this solution?